# Designing inheritence in Java

Tags: java, oop

I've to design the following scenario.

2 Classes - **Square** - methods - draw() and calculateLength(int a)
   **Triangle** has methods draw() and and calculateLength(int a, int b)

later in the development adding a new class **Circle** - has methods draw() and calculateLength(int a, int b, int c)...
so when it comes to Circle  class, The application should enforce the class to implement draw and calculateLength ..

I was thinking of creating a Interface called Shape and which has draw() method but when it comes to **Triangle** calculateLength also should be enforced to implement..

Suggest me the best way to design this scenario...

Comment: If your only common method is `draw`, that's the only one that can go on a common interface.

Comment: Why does the calculate length method need parameters? Shouldnt each instance keep track of the appropriate side lengths?

Comment: Ben...thats the requirement need to design..

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of an interface is that it provides a guarantee to other classes that method X specified in the interface will be accessible. Based on the info you've provided, that doesn't seem important here.
You cannot give the methods in an interface a method body unless they are static (which does not seem useful for your example).
For this scenario, you'll want objects to be in the same class/subclasses of each other if they use portions of the same code. Are the calculateLength methods in Square and Circle exactly the same? I can imagine a scenario in which they would be. In that situation, inheriting from the same superclass and not having to re-write methods/data members would be useful.